# Looking for a way to create tile based movement in ActionScript

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

(Try number two...)

So, I've started to program a game in AS3. I'm looking for a way to create a smooth, tile based movement system, like that seen in a Pokemon game or other. I can decrease or increase the x or y values of the players position, but I run into some problems. The first would be that with more than one person in the party, they don't really follow the player. They just stay behind them when moving left (The way I set it up). When I move upwards, they stay beside the player, same with downwards, and they stay infront of the player when moving right. is There a possible way I can make a symbol titled "char" take movement commands, and "char2" and so on stay a certain amount of tiles away from said player.

Thanks,
Jacob

EDIT: Sorry! Forgot to attach the code. It's below now!

```
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, cameraFollowplayeracter);
function cameraFollowplayeracter(evt:Event)
{
    root.scrollRect = new Rectangle(char.x - stage.stageWidth/2, char.y - stage.stageHeight/2, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
}
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyPressed);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, onKeyReleased);
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, gameLoop);
var score = 0;
var charSpeed = 6;
char.x = 128;
char4.x = char.x + 14;
char.y = 96;
char4.y = char.y;
var charFacing = 0;
//charFacing works as the following:
//0 = down, 1 = up, 2 = left, and 3 = right
char.gotoAndStop("charDown");
char4.gotoAndStop("char4Down");
var isLeftKeyDown = false;
var isRightKeyDown = false;
var isUpKeyDown = false;
var isDownKeyDown = false;
function onKeyPressed(evt:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        isLeftKeyDown = true;
        charFacing = 2;
        char.gotoAndStop ("charLeft");
        char4.gotoAndStop("char4Left");
    }
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        isRightKeyDown = true;
        charFacing = 3;
        char.gotoAndStop ("charRight");
        char4.gotoAndStop("char4Right");
    }
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        isUpKeyDown = true;
        charFacing = 1;
        char.gotoAndStop ("charUp");
        char4.gotoAndStop("char4Up");
    }
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        isDownKeyDown = true;
        charFacing = 0;
        char.gotoAndStop ("charDown");
        char4.gotoAndStop("char4Down");
    }
}
function onKeyReleased(evt:KeyboardEvent)
{
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.LEFT)
    {
        isLeftKeyDown = false;
    }
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.RIGHT)
    {
        isRightKeyDown = false;
    }
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.UP)
    {
        isUpKeyDown = false;
    }
    if(evt.keyCode == Keyboard.DOWN)
    {
        isDownKeyDown = false;
    }
}

function gameLoop(evt:Event)
{
    scoreDisplay.x = char.x - 120;
    scoreDisplay.y = char.y - 90;
    if(char.hitTestObject(cheese) && cheese.visible == true)
    {
        cheese.visible = false;
        score = score + 100;
        scoreDisplay.text = "SCORE:" + score;
    }
    if(isLeftKeyDown == true)
    {
        char.x-=charSpeed;
        char4.moveTo(char + 14);
    }
    if(isRightKeyDown == true)
    {
        char.x+=charSpeed;
        char4.x+=charSpeed;
    }
    if(isUpKeyDown == true)
    {
        char.y-=charSpeed;
        char4.y-=charSpeed;
    }
    if(isDownKeyDown == true)
    {
        char.y+=charSpeed;
        char4.y+=charSpeed;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're gonna need to show some code or something more than this.

Comment: @Tyler Sorry! I should've attached something like that. It should be in the OP now!

Answer (score 0):

I only took a quick skim through your code, though, my thought is that if you want a character to follow your character, one way can be to cache/save the last move of that player and get the character to follow that move, rather then using the same current move of the player.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be quite interesting question.
First what you would do is detach NPC movement from your lead character.

I.e. what you are doing now: key pressed - character faces some direction and runs, key released - character stops. And all characters do it at the same time.

What is needed: key pressed - only lead character runs, key released - only lead character stops. Other characters (NPCs) must be controlled not by key events, but their own logic. They can run while the lead character stands or they can stand while the lead character runs. They can also face directions different from the lead charater.

So, how would i do it:

1) Define a number of formations. A formation is a way your characters take places around your lead character. It can be set by different means but a most practical one would be just a 3x3 matrix I think. It can accomodate up to 8 NPCs. For example, this is the standing formation:

```
1 2 3
4 & 5
6 7 8
```

Here `&` means your lead characters and other characters (1..8) are standing around. If you have less characters, the formation might be defined as

```
  1
2 & 3
  4
```

etc. Or you just can choose any random vacant places in the formation.
Now, when player starts to move, formation changes:

```
1 2 3
4 5 &
6 7 8
```

This is, of course, moving right. Correspondingly, here are the examples for others directions:

```
& 1 2    1 & 2    1 2 &    1 2 3    1 2 3
3 4 5    3 4 5    3 4 5    4 5 6    4 5 6
6 7 8    6 7 8    6 7 8    7 & 8    7 8 &
```

and so on. Note that you can also use any custom formations for different direction, for example, moving right can look like this:

```
1
2 6 
3 7 &
4 8
5
```

Next step, each formation needs to be coded. Each position in a formation has a relative offset from the lead character position. From example above, position 6 has offset (-1,-1), position 7 has offset (-1, 0), position 8 has offset (-1, 1) etc. So each formation can be coded that way.

Now comes the main part. Once the lead character started moving, choose an appropriate formation for the given direction. Assign each NPC a place in that formation (can be chosen randomly from a list of vacant places).

Now, while the lead character moves, you should take its coordinates and check each NPC how far their formation position is from these coordinates. If is is closer than offset coded for this position, stop and do nothing. If it is farther, then define a direction based on the difference (which can be different from lead character direction) and start moving in that direction.

The logic is like this:

1. get the lead character x, y (lead_x, lead_y)
2. for each NPC:
3. get NPC's formation position
4. get offset_x, offset_y for that position
5. set NPC destination x, y = lead_x + offset_x, lead_y + offset_y
6. get distance between current NPC's x,y and destination x,y
7. if distance is not zero, find the direction in which NPC should move to reach the destination, and start moving, else stop moving.